# How to match actual hostname in ssh config?

Tags: openssh

I got the following entries in my `.ssh/config`:

```
Host *.onion
 ProxyCommand socat - SOCKS4A:localhost:%h:%p,socksport=9050

Host hidden-dev
  Hostname blablahash.onion
```

this config worked fine on Debian jessie, yet after upgrade to stretch, this config doesn't seem to work, it seems that Host `*.onion` line matches the alias name, instead of the actual hostname. Any clues what I should do ?

Comment: Have you tried to swap the entries around? Put hidden-dev BEFORE *.onion. Or use `hidden-dev.onion` instead of shorter `hidded-dev`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a mix of multiple answers and comments and and it worked:

Putting the following line after 'hidden-dev' entry worked:

```
Match Host *.onion
  ProxyCommand socat - SOCKS4A:localhost:%h:%p,socksport=9050
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Host canonical *.onion` for two-pass lookup.

Comment: This gives a syntax error